# Show that $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$.

Tags: inequality

Show that $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$.

I know this probably applies the triangle inequality in some way, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hint: $|-y| = |y|$

Comment: "The distance from $x$ to $y$ is $\le$ the distance from $x$ to $0$ to $y$"

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. $$|x-y| = |x+(-y)| \leq \text{?}$$
and then use the property $|-z| = |z|$.